# помогите с логикой python

Tags: python, for

вообщем есть код python

```
for profile_id in all_profile:

           change_ip()

           print(f'Обновил ip - {clear_proxy_ip}')

           edit_profile(profile_id=profile_id, input_proxy_ip=clear_proxy_ip)

           print(f'Настраиваю профиль - {profile_id}')



           with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as base_file:

               for line in base_file:

                      ....
```

и мне нужно чтобы для каждого profile_id код выполнял работу с каждой line в data.txt, а у меня он для одного айди профиля делает все строки до конца, как это можно сделать? голову убил, не соображаю вообще

Comment: Если all_profile и base_file разное количество строк, что должно быть?

Comment: @Oopss когда строки где либо заканчиваются, конец работы кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as base_file:
    lines=base_file.read().split('\n')

for profile_id,line in zip(all_profile,lines):
    change_ip()
    print(f'Обновил ip - {clear_proxy_ip}')
    edit_profile(profile_id=profile_id, input_proxy_ip=clear_proxy_ip)
    print(f'Настраиваю профиль - {profile_id}')
    print(profile_id,line)
```

Comment: спасибо большое <3, работает как надо

Comment: по строкам надо разбить